# Snapshot Recordset Update on Movenext

Tags: compare, updates, recordset, snapshot

I have a main form (DeliveryDockets) and subform (DeliveryDocketLines).  In the main forms OnLoad event I am setting a snapshot recordset.

```
Set oldRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM DeliveryDocketLines WHERE (DelDocketID = " & Me.DelDocketID & ");", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
```

then after the user has made changes to the subform data, I want to check to see what changes have been made, so in the OnClick event of the Save button I have the following

```
Set newRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM DeliveryDocketLines WHERE (DelDocketID = " & Me.DelDocketID & ");", dbOpenDynaset)
oldRS.MoveFirst
Do While Not oldRS.EOF
    newRS.FindFirst ("[ID] = " & oldRS![ID])
    If newRS![DeliveryQTY] <> oldRS![DeliveryQTY] Then
        'record has changed
    End If
    oldRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

This works for the first record in oldRS, but as soon as you move past the first record, the oldRS gets updated to the newRS values.

Does this have something to do with setting the recordset from a SELECT statement?

I thought that the Snapshot was supposed to not allow this.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Did you fix this? Did you have to open a new connection?